# Ruby OpenCv Template matching threshold

Tags: ruby, opencv, template-matching

I am trying to make template matching on a picture in order to find all the matches. To make this, I want to use a threshold between 0 and 1 to have a way to stop the process. I am using the following code:

```
require 'opencv'
include OpenCV

template_filename = (ARGV.size == 2) ? ARGV[0] : File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lena-eyes.jpg')
match_image_filename = (ARGV.size == 2) ? ARGV[1] : File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lena-256x256.jpg')

template = CvMat.load(template_filename)
match_image = CvMat.load(match_image_filename)

10.times.each do |t|
  result = match_image.match_template(template, :sqdiff_normed)
  #result = result.normalize(0, 1, CV_NORM_MINMAX, -1, nil)

  pt1 = result.min_max_loc[2]
  pt2 = CvPoint.new(pt1.x + template.width, pt1.y + template.height)
  match_image.rectangle!(pt1, pt2, :color => CvColor::Black, :thickness => 3)
end

window = GUI::Window.new('Display window')
window.show(match_image)
```

The problem is that the min and max values that I obtain with the match_template are not between 0 and 1, so I am not able to use the threshold. The first result has the following min and max values: [0.00011, 0.4955]. The other results, which are invalid, has the following min and max values: [0.1190, 0.5369], [0.1296, 0.5369]...

I have tried to use the normalize method with the result but its always give me 0 and 1 as min and max values.

I have been surfing on Internet and I can not find the error on my code. Is there any way to normalize the result min and max values between 0 and 1?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Couldn't you apply some arithmetic and boolean logic with min and max to check if you should break the loop?

Comment: I want to break the loop when a result is lower or upper than a threshold but the values of min and max values don't permit me to do it.

Comment: You mean that you don't know what the boundaries should be? You'd expect min and max to fall outside of `(0..1)` when something goes wrong?

Comment: Not exactly. I expect that the min or max value would be equal/similar to 0 when it is a correct match and another higher value (less than 1) when it is a bad match. However the bad matches are always with a mix value between 0.11 and 0.15 and max value between 0.53 and 0.55.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution. After reading deeply the [template matching article](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) on the official OpenCV documentation, I have converted the match_image to grayscale and I have changed the template matching method for using the CCOEFF_NORMED method. With this method, the point of the match is given by the max loc (result.min_max_loc[3]).

Now, the max value is almost equal to 1 when its an exact match and it descends when the match is similar but not equal.

```
require 'opencv'
include OpenCV

template_filename = (ARGV.size == 2) ? ARGV[0] : File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lena-eyes.jpg')
match_image_filename = (ARGV.size == 2) ? ARGV[1] : File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lena-256x256.jpg')

template = CvMat.load(template_filename)
match_image = CvMat.load(match_image_filename)
match_image.BGR2GRAY

10.times.each do |t|
  result = match_image.match_template(template, :ccoeff_normed)
  pt1 = result.min_max_loc[3]
  pt2 = CvPoint.new(pt1.x + template.width, pt1.y + template.height)
  match_image.rectangle!(pt1, pt2, :color => CvColor::Black, :thickness => 3)
end

window = GUI::Window.new('Display window')
window.show(match_image)
```